# Match two identical images with different filenames

Tags: c#, image

if a single image has been saved twice with two different filenames, is there a way to compare them to see if they're the same..?

I'm hoping a basic hash or CRC type check could work..?

File size might not, as there are millions of images in the pool and different images could have the same size..

Hoping there's an easy way to do it in C#..

Comment: What is the average size of the images ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file contents are identical, then a cryptographic hash would at least give a very good indication of equality. The [`SHA256`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) class would be a good candidate here, although it's possibly a little over the top. For example:

```
static byte[] Sha256HashFile(string file)
{
    using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            return sha256.ComputeHash(input);
        }
    }
}
```

The simplest way to compare the two returned byte arrays is probably to convert them both to strings using `Convert.ToBase64` and then compare the strings. Ugly but easy :) You could also use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`:

```
byte[] hash1 = Sha256HashFile("file1.png");
byte[] hash2 = Sha256HashFile("file2.png");
bool same = hash1.SequenceEqual(hash2);
```

If you want to store the hashes as a set or dictionary, you *could* implement your own `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` but frankly it would be easiest to use a base64 string. For example, this will print out the duplicate files:

```
var hashToNameMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    byte[] hash = Sha256HashFile(file);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64(hash);
    string existingName;
    if (hashToNameMap.TryGetValue(base64, out existingName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a duplicate of {1}", file, existingName);
    }
    else
    {
        hashToNameMap[base64] = file;
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- This isn't *guaranteed* to be accurate, but the chances of getting a collision are very small, particularly if the files also have to be valid images.
- This involves reading *all* of *every* file - even if there are no other files with the same size (and therefore no possible duplicates). This may or may not be an issue for you.
- Even if there *are* multiple files of the same size, you only need to read all of them to find duplicates... you could potentially read the files and compute the hashes as you go, stopping as soon as you find that files are different.

How you approach this depends on whether your goal is absolute speed, simplicity of code, etc. It may also depend on whether the pool will grow over time - for example, you may want to hash files as soon as you get two or more files of the same size, so that when you add another file of the same size you can hash *that* and add it without ever rereading the existing data.

Comment: +1 (@Jon Skeet - congrats on 300K rep :) ). As Henk Holterman points out simple hash algorithm may be as good for this case and likely be faster compared to Crypto ones. But Sha* are likely the easiest to write code with.

Comment: FWIW: I realize this is a somewhat old thread, but on two identical 100 MB bitmap files, it took ~7 seconds using the method you've described here, and ~200 milliseconds to read in both files and compare them byte by byte.

Comment: @Anders: On the other hand, if there are *lots* of files to compare, you can compare *hashes* very quickly, but you don't want to do a pairwise comparison of each of those files. There are ways round this, mind you - I have used it as an interview question before... One other time this is useful is if you occasionally add files to the pool. Storing all the hashes means you'd only ever need to hash the new file, only comparing it with *any* others if you get a hash match.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you for the insight, you make some very valid points - a pairwise comparison on millions of files would take a very, very long time... yikes!  I misread the question; I was thinking he had one image, and was looking for its duplicate, not looking for any duplicates of any image.  Either way though, I can see how useful it would be to build up a database of hashes for future use.

Answer (score 4):

First, check the length anyway. Only when they match you have to look deeper.

For all images with the same size, compute a Hash. When the hashes match you can be fairly sure the images are identical. The library offers many cryptographically secure hashes but you may want to look for optimizations:

- Sample. If your images are large (> 100 kB) you can save on I/O by computing the hash over a few segments only. A few kB at the start, middle and end is probably enough to get a good fingerprint. Do use multiples of 512 for the sizes and offsets of those blocks.  Jpeg compression works a little like a Hash: a few pixels difference usually lead to big differences in the bitstream.
- use a faster hash. A simple xor algorithm might suffice in this case.
- If you really want to compare 2 images at a time then use a Hash implementation that let's you check intermediate results. As soon as there's a difference you can stop.
- But when you have a lot of same-size files, compute the Hash once per file and find the (Size, Hash) duplicates.

Comment: And if hash collisions are an issue, a byte-for-byte comparison is cheap once you've found a collision.

Comment: I think the choice of hash algorithm will depend on whether it's CPU-bound or IO-bound. But yes, there are clearly options there.

Comment: @Jon, yes, my two suggestions are in the wrong order. I'll edit a little.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
System.Security.Cryptography;
```

use SHA1

```
using(SHA1 sha = SHA1.Create()) { //added using based on Jon Skeet comment
    byte[] newData = sha.ComputeHash(data);
}
```

data is the byte[] data of the file

newData is the hash

This is only appropriate if you want to know if the two images files are literally the same bytes, not if they just encode the same pixels (which could be different files if meta-data is different)

Comment: Note that HashAlgorithm implements IDisposable, so you should dispose of the SHA1 afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the binary from each file and then compare the binary contained. The same image should have the exact same binary in each array.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
                            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{ 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    { 
         // Convert Image to byte[]
         image.Save(ms, format);  
         byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String; 
    }
}
```

then you can just do a `String.Compare()`. This is probably slow for larger pictures because it generates a pretty large string but I have posted it just for the sake of completnes:)